# How to shift rows values as columns in pandas?

Tags: python, data, pandas, csv

**Input:** I have csv file like below as input....

```
ID, Year,Specialty,AgeRange,PlaceSvc,Count, Group
101,2009,Internal,  20-29,  Office,     0,  PRGNCY
101,2010,Emergency, 20-29,  Urgent Care,0,  GIOBSENT
101,2011,Internal,  20-29,  Office,     0,  GYNEC1
102,2010,Other,     30-39,  Office,     1,  PRGNCY
102,2010,Laboratory,30-39,  Independent,1,  MSC2a3
103,2009,Laboratory,30-39,  Independent,1,  MSC2a3
103,2011,Other,     30-39,  Office,     0,  PRGNCY
```

**Output:** I want output like below...

```
ID,Year,Specialty_Internal,Specialty_Emergency,Specialty_Labrotory,Specialty_Other,Age20_29,Age30_39,PlaceSvc_Urgent,PlaceSvc_Office,PlaceSvc_Independent,Count,GroupPrgncy,GroupGiobsent,GroupGynec1,GroupMsc2a3

101,2009,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,0
101,2010,0,1,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0
101,2011,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,0
102,2010,0,0,1,1,0,1,0,1,1,2,1,0,0,1
103,2009,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,1
103,2011,0,0,0,1,,1,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,0
```

How can i do this by pandas? or is there any other techinque to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want [pandas.get_dummies](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.get_dummies.html).

If you call `get_dummies` on a categorical column, it will output the binary dummy variables you're looking for. You should then be able to merge this with your original DataFrame on the index, or construct a new DataFrame using only the columns you want.

Comment: It is making all column as categorical column. Is it possible to not to make Year column as category?

Comment: Yes. Filter out your `year` column before feeding it into the `get_dummies` function. You might want to look at `DataFrame.merge` and `pandas.concat` if you're not already familiar with them, as this will let you construct a new DataFrame using your new columns.